# How do I use a Static class in Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, global-asax

I have a Global.asax where I define routes (see RegisterRoutes method below)

I will have a lot of routes, so I would like keep this method in a separate static class, importing using a namespace in the Global Asax and use the method in the Application_Start.

Unfortunately I'm not able to do it.

So my question:

- Can I use static class in Global.asax?
- If yes, how can I do it?

  ```
  void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
  {
      // Register a route for Categories/All
      routes.MapPageRoute(
              "All Categories",       // Route name
              "Categories/All",       // Route URL
              "~/AllCategories.aspx"   // Web page to handle route
          );

      // Register a route for Products/{ProductName}
      routes.MapPageRoute(
          "View Content",             // Route name
          "Content/{ContentId}",   // Route URL
          "~/Cms/FrontEndCms/Content.aspx"        // Web page to handle route
      );

  }

  protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      // ROUTING.
      RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks Nathan Koop for your corrections :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely be able to do this:

```
  protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ROUTING.
        Helper.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }


public static class Helper
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        // Register a route for Categories/All
        routes.MapPageRoute(
                "All Categories",       // Route name
                "Categories/All",       // Route URL
                "~/AllCategories.aspx"   // Web page to handle route
            );

        // Register a route for Products/{ProductName}
        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "View Content",             // Route name
            "Content/{ContentId}",   // Route URL
            "~/Cms/FrontEndCms/Content.aspx"        // Web page to handle route
        );

}
```